# Paytm refund api gives 501 - System error in response

Tags: php, paytm

I am using paytm refund api in php.

here is my code:

```
$checkSum = "";
$paramList = array();            
// Create an array having all required parameters for creating checksum.
$paramList["MID"] = '**********';
$paramList["ORDERID"] = '*******'; //get during paytm transaction response
$paramList["TXNTYPE"] = 'REFUND';
$paramList["REFUNDAMOUNT"] = '50';
$paramList["TXNID"] = '***********'; // get during paytm transaction response
$paramList["REFID"] = 'REFID'.time();
//Here checksum string will return by getChecksumFromArray() function.
$checkSum = getRefundChecksumFromArray($paramList,PAYTM_MERCHANT_KEY);
$paramList["CHECKSUM"] = urlencode($checkSum);
$data_string = 'JsonData='.json_encode($paramList);
// initiate curl
$ch = curl_init();                    
$url = 'https://securegw-stage.paytm.in/refund/HANDLER_INTERNAL/REFUND';
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);  // tell curl you want to post something
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$data_string); // define what you want to post
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); // return the output in string format
$headers = array();
$headers[] = 'Content-Type: application/json';
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
$output = curl_exec ($ch); // execute
$info = curl_getinfo($ch);
$data = json_decode($output, true);
print_r($data);
```

Here is the response, i am getting:

```
Array ( [RESPCODE] => 501 [RESPMSG] => System Error. [STATUS] => PENDING )
```

I am not getting that what this system error means. What is the solution for this. Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks in advance..

Comment: Have you tried asking the support of your payment provider?

Comment: yes, i have posted my issue in forum support discussion also, and did not get the response yet for the solution.

Comment: Hi Hetal, I am facing same issue. Status :"PENDING" and Code : 501. Did you resolve this ?

Comment: What solution did you find @HetalChauhan. I have a similar issue.

Answer (score 2):

According to the error doc error 501 is an system error inside payTm.
https://developer.paytm.com/docs/refund-status-api/

I guess you are using payTm staging server. There is nothing wrong from your side, I suggest you to wait a few hours and try again. it will automatically work

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue because i had not declared the value of PAYTM_MERCHANT_KEY
before passing it to getRefundChecksumFromArray

```
$checkSum = getRefundChecksumFromArray($paramList,PAYTM_MERCHANT_KEY);
```

This line of code solved it

```
define("PAYTM_MERCHANT_KEY", "your_key_goes_here");
```